# Android Left and Right Arrow Keys Act as Back and Previous Buttons

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-softkeyboard

I am working on an application with multiple fragments. Under One fragment I have some text editable fields. Every time the user clicks on this field, enters a text and clicks on the left or right arrow keys , post navigating through the field the the left or right arrow key act as a back or previous button navigating to the next/previous fragment (next/previous screen).

I have the following xml fields with some custom

```
<com.UI.widget.UIEditText
            android:id="@+id/userinfo_lastnameinput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:maxLength="20"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:singleLine="true" 
            android:inputType="textPersonName" android:paddingTop="5dp"/>
```

The corresponding Java code is :

```
// Initialize the variable 
    mLastNameInput = (UIEditText) this.findViewById(R.id.userinfo_lastnameinput);
    mLastNameInput.clearFocus();
    lastNameTextChangeListener();

private void lastNameTextChangeListener() {
    mLastNameInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (mInitialLoad) {
                return;
            }

            mLastNameVar.setValue(mLastNameInput.getText().toString().trim());
            mLastNameInput.setIsPending(mLastNameVar.isPending());


        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                      int arg2, int arg3) {
            // Do nothing

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                  int arg3) {
            // Do nothing

        }
    });
}
```

How can I restrict this behavior, such that the arrow keys only move within the editable field.

Comment: Check this link
http://codepen.io/asommer70/blog/android-fragments-buttons-and-activities for more clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also could create fragments dynamically like so

```
// Create new fragment and     
transaction Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();     
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment, // and add the transaction to the back stack if needed

```
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);     

transaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

// Commit the transaction

```
transaction.commit();
```

And just use 
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, "class and/or increment");
Preferably under button designed. Just use your XML coded fragment as a container